# Accessing to a lot of text in Phonegap on all platforms without writing native code

Tags: database, data-structures, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm making app with ~200 text files, each file contains ~50000 symbols (it will contain more files later). App will work offline, so text must be prepopulated. First thing about which I thought was usage of databases. But after I googled, I found that it's currently not possible to access SQL prepopulated databases in Phonegap without writing native code and other databases max sizes are too small for my needs.

I need only to read data (writing isn't necessarily).

Is it possible using database? 

Is it ok to use JSON/XML/HTML/other file or separate files to store needed text? Won't it cause performance problems? 

Is there more suitable approach?

Comment: I think it depends on how you're going to use the data. Is it just for listing or are you going to perform calculations or selecting subsets of data? But spontaneously I don't see a bit problem with shipping your files together with the initial deploy with the app and on first load create the database and load your data.

Comment: @gaqzi It's just for listing. I'm afraid that creating database on load will take more and more time, because I plan to significantly increase amount of text files. And this will likely annoy users.

Comment: If it's just for listing I would save it as JSON as close to as I would want to display the files and just list them that way. Using `FileTransfer` it would be fairly easy to update a local library of files as needed without having to resubmit the app.